# Is there a web app that allows you to enter a webapp and it gives you a list of similar websites?

Tags: webapp-rec

Let's say I want to find other services similar to Google Docs. Is there a website that allows me to type in **Google Docs** and it gives me 10 competing web apps?

Or if I typed in **gmail** it would give me YahooMail, HotMail, etc.

Or if I typed in **screenr.com** it would give me 10 other sites that allow you to create screencasts.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [alternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/) which does exactly what you're asking for and not only for webapps, but also for Windows, MacOS, Linux, iPhone, Android, etc..

Comment: @Edward for the `screenr.com` alternatives skip the `.com` part to get relevant results.